# Can I replay stages in Mega Man X?

Tags: mega-man-x

Can I replay a stage in Mega Man X after defeating the robot master?

I missed a heart tank upgrade in Armored Armadillo's stage. If I defeat the boss and finish the stage, will I be able to come back later for the upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can always reenter the 8 main maverick  stages in Mega Man X along with the other Mega Man X games. Reentering stages multiple times is actually required to get 100% completion.

Comment: Also note that once you've beaten the stage, you can exit it through the weapon select screen without having to go all the way to the end again.